# How to check if a function parameter is a Normalizr schema class?

Tags: normalizr

Is there any way to check, **at runtime**, if a function parameter is (or not) a Normalizr schema class? Could be any type: entity, array, object, etc.

For example:

```
function processTMDBRespose(response, schema) {
  // if 'schema' param is not a normalizr schema, throw!

  // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and can't do what you're looking for.

*If* you write yourself a lint rule that only allows creating schema from normalizr classes, like `new schema.Array()` and prohibits the use of shorthand `[]`, then you can check using `instanceof`:

```
if (
    mySchema instanceof schema.Array || 
    mySchema instanceof schema.Entity ||
    mySchema instanceof schema.Object ||
    mySchema instanceof schema.Union ||
    mySchema instanceof schema.Values
) { 
    // your  code
} else {
    throw new Error('mySchema is not a schema');
}
```

However, if you use shorthand, any array `[]` or plain object `{}` is also a valid schema for `schema.Array` and `schema.Object`, respectively. This is much more difficult to validate, because almost everything is `typeof Object` in JavaScript (like `null`)